# How can I calculate the each weeks revenue and write to the weekly sum column in Excel?

Tags: excel, window-functions

I am using Excel to find weekly revenue.

To do that, I have got 3 columns: ISOWEEK, REVENUE, and WEEKLY SUM. I want to add all the revenue done in the same week and write them into the WEEKLY SUM column. So that WEEK1 will have its own SUM1, WEEK2 will have its own SUM2, etc. Please check the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyzlL.png)

How can I do it, can you please help?

Thanks.

Comment: [`SUMIF()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) will do just fine =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JvdV suggested:

Put this in C2 and copy the formula down. Depending on your Excel setup, change ";" to ","

> =sumif(A:A;A2;B:B)